# lengthChange doesn't show when I add button(print) in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm having problem of how to show both `lengthChange` and `print` button.

Here's my **code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.table-driver').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "ajax": "{{route('users.show')}}",
        "columns": [ 
            { "data": "name", name: "name" },
            { "data": "rate", rate: "rate" },
            { "data": "age", age: "age" },
            { "data": "status", status: "status" },
            {"data":"action", action: "action", sort: false}
        ], 
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'print'
        ] 
    });
});
```

Here's the **output:**[image]

And my **desired output:**
[image]

Beginner of datatables, someone could help me about this please. thanks in adv. Sirs.

Comment: Here is the doc of Page Length Options : https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html

Comment: I just test the first JFiddle I found and it seems not work at all at the same time. Button are shown (edit, delete...) but not the page length selector.

Comment: It actually works in mine Sir @Shim-Sao, the only problem is that, the page length selector doesn't show when I put button(print) together. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I know, I have just tested something before answer ;) You can look in HTML if is it a problem of HTML/CSS or if nothing is rendered for PageLength selector. If nothing you have to choose or create your own buttons.

Comment: I double check html and css's, I think "DOM Positioning" could solve this problem, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Exact, I found the solution : https://datatables.net/reference/button/pageLength

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this and I added `l` to the dom element

like this

```
dom: 'Blfrtip',
```

notice the difference

> 'Bfrtip' and 'Blfrtip'

Answer (score 1):

Here is the doc of Page Length Options : https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html

Add option :

```
"lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
```

Add pageLength to the buttons list :
https://datatables.net/reference/button/pageLength

```
buttons: [ 'pageLength', ... ]
```

Comment: My problem Sir @Shim-Sao is, the lengthChange/pageLength will not show when I put button(print).

Comment: can you help me Sir how to that "desired output". I took so long on solving that, end up nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you

```
$('#t1').DataTable({dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'csv'
        ]});    
  });
```